# How to return reference of unique_ptr<Derived> from unique_ptr<Base>?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, unique-ptr, c++20

I work with unique_ptr on derived structs, and I return references to maintain ownership and keep minimal overhead.

Basically, I want a get function to turn `unique_ptr<Base>` into `unique_ptr<Derived>&`.

- I can't use dynamic_pointer_cast as it copies and fails :
  `no matching function for call to 'dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(std::unique_ptr<Base>&)'`
- I can't use std::move or release from `obj`, as it is the source of truth of the program.

Do you guys see any alternative? 
The shared_ptr version works OK btw, is it the only path?

Thanks in advance for your input.
JD

```
#include <memory>

struct Base {

};
struct Derived : public Base {
    float position;
    Derived(float position_) : position(position_) {}
};

//SOURCE OF TRUTH
std::unique_ptr<Base> obj; 


//retreive from obj
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T>& get() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> &p = obj;
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(p); //<-- pb: fails because it copies...
}


int main() {
    //storing
    obj = std::make_unique<Derived>(10.0f);

    // ...

    //retrieving
    std::unique_ptr<Derived>& p = get<Derived>();   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can return a pointer or reference to the object being held in the unique_ptr instead. It's perfectly fine to pass non-owning pointers around as long as you never manually `delete` anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still just do a regular `dynamic_cast` with the raw pointer, ie.:

```
template<typename T>
T* get() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> &p = obj;
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(p.get());
}
```

Semanticly that is ok as raw pointer is taken to mean non-owning.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that `obj` is points to anything, let alone a `T`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I had to add a virtual function in Base, otherwise it rejects the dynamic_cast (no cast on non-polymorphic). Seems to do the job now. Will test and accept .

Comment: @JBDumont your `Base` class should have a virtual destructor, that will suffice to satisfy `dynamic_cast`, while also ensuring that when `unique_ptr` deletes a `Base*` pointer it will call the `Derived` destructor correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`get` should return a non-owning pointer, because it shouldn't be changing the ownership.

```
template<typename T>
T * get() {
    return std::dynamic_cast<T *>(obj.get());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Don't!
Long Answer: A unique pointer deals with ownership and a reference has no ownership semantic. You may return a (const) reference instead. If you need to share ownership use std::shared_pointer.

Comment: I see your point. I just wanted to borrow locally, but if owner dies we are SF. In my case, the owner will have a longer lifespan ( which I didn't mention) so should be fine.  For short term owners, I'll stick to shared_ptr as you remind me.